# Imagick - When resizing, image gets blurry

Tags: php, pdf, resize, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to resize a pdf (which i converted from image), and I am trying to resize (increase) the image in its ratio.

```
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->readImage($path);

$imagick->resizeImage(595,842,\Imagick::FILTER_CUBIC, 1, true);

// and this:
// $imagick->adaptiveResizeImage(595,842, true); 

$imagick->setImageFormat('pdf');
$imagick->writeImage($endpath);
```

But the image is getting blurry. However, it's not a bad quality image and the image can go that size without getting disturbed. (For example, if I let Twilio to do it (via fax api), the same image can get to that scale).

I have also tried with putting blur parameter of resizeImage between '1' and '0.1'

Original pdf (you can also [see it here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ppw79RfKyySUhvGO0Bg2PNtD3bIqYOn_), if you want to try):

[image]

My resized pdf (with blur 1):

[image]

My "adaptive resized" pdf:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting with a very small pdf if rasterized and enlarging. So that would cause blurring. But if you increase the input density, it works fine for me in ImageMagick as

```
convert -density 600 input.pdf -resize 595x842 result.png
```

I do not know Imagick well, but try the following. Reduce the blur value in resizeImage as desired to make it sharper.

```
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->readImage($path);
$imagick->Imagick::setImageResolution( 600, 600 );
$imagick->resizeImage(595,842,\Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1, true);
$imagick->setImageFormat('pdf');
$imagick->writeImage($endpath);
```

Comment: I am trying to convert "pdf to pdf", instead of "pdf to png". `$imagick->Imagick::setImageResolution( 600, 600 );` only makes the size of the page 600x600. I think this is not the answer.

Comment: setImageResolution, I believe is setting the density. Read the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageresolution.php. When reading a PDF, you must set the density before reading the PDF. Using a large density makes the rasterized image dimensions larger. Then you can resize to a smaller dimension and get good quality results.

Comment: [Your answer here](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=33430) - helps a lot understanding Resolutions